# insert phone number in a table

Tags: asp.net, parameters, insert, string-formatting

How to insert a phone number into a table using asp.net?

```
string insertquery = 
    "insert customer (
        id, name, address, gender, DOB, contactno, email, userid, password)
    values
        (@custid, @custname, @custaddress, @gender, @custdob,
        @custcno, @custemail, @custuserid, @custpassword)";
```

Here custcno is the phone number.

```
 sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custcno",Convert.ToInt32(txtcustcno.Text));
```

While running I'm getting error Input string was not in a correct format.

in table contactno is varchar(50)

Comment: If a number is not to be calculated with, it is not a number. Phone numbers are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is trying to convert the telephone number string to a number here:

```
Convert.ToInt32(txtcustcno.Text)
```

So, if it contains any non-numeric characters like dashes of parentheses then it'll throw an exception.

To just insert the string without first converting it, do this:

```
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custcno", txtcustcno.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure from the question: why `Convert.ToInt32`? many phone number formats have spaces, dashes, ( & ). these will cause  `Convert.ToInt32` to throw `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Preform input validation using ASP.NET validation controls (or whatever) and do this:

```
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custcno",txtcustcno.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert the phone number to an int. Change your parameter to:

```
 sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custcno",txtcustcno.Text);
```